# How to pass in multiple parameters to web.py's render

Tags: python, templates, jinja2, web.py

I am using `Jinja2` with `web.py` and have come across what seems to be a simple problem. I am rendering my paramertized html files and can't seem to figure out how to pass in multiple parameter=value pairs without typing each on in as arguments. I tried passing in a `dict` and list of strings with no success.

If I want to render `home.html` which has five parameters that need values, how can I pass in their values without having to type `param1=value1, param2=value2` as arguments to the reder.home() function?

I was hoping something like this would work:

```
from web.contrib.template import render_jinja
render = render_jinja('templates', encoding = 'utf-8',)

p = {}
p['param1'] = 56
p['param2'] = 'something'
...

render.home(p)
```

PS. the `web.py` template examples seem to only cover the single param example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dictionary expansion, like so

```
render.home(**p)
```